# IEnumerable<T>'s value changes every time I try to inspect it in debug mode in VS2022

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

In 4 years of C# soft engineering I have never encountered something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/QibVxyy).
I thought Debugger's value inspect feature should not change inspected value's raw value, but I guess Debugger doesn't agree with that.

So, I have a rough idea why this might happen, and even found a similar [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609950/for-loop-variable-within-ienumerable-changes-value) in Microsoft's C# forum, but not very sure of it. Also, when I returned newMsg and tried to call .ToArray() multiple times in a row, it gave different values to each call. My theory is, that every time I try to get IEnumerable's value, it does a recursive LINQ command, that in the process changes its datasource.

```
public IEnumerable<byte> Shift(IEnumerable<byte> msg)
{
    var parts = msg.Chunk(blockLength);
    var keyEnumerator = shifter.GetEnumerator();
    var newMsg = parts.SelectMany(part =>
    {
        if (!keyEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            keyEnumerator = shifter.GetEnumerator();
            //keyEnumerator.Reset();
            keyEnumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        byte shift = (byte)(keyEnumerator.Current % blockLength);
        var res = part.TakeLast(blockLength - shift).Concat(part.Take(shift));
        //Debug.Write(string.Join('-', res.Select(i => $"{i:X2}")) + "-");
        return res;
    });

    return TextManipualtion.UnPadByteIEnumerable(newMsg);
}
```

Can someone explain if this is a real bug or is it intended to be like this.

One of the reasons of this problem may also be that without `Reset()` enumerator cant work properly but there is a code under shows that you can reset enumerator by calling `GetEnumerator()` again.

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
var atro = ints.GetEnumerator();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    atro.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(atro.Current);
}

atro = ints.GetEnumerator();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    atro.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(atro.Current);
}

//Output
//0
//1
//0
//1
//2
//3
```

Comment: What does `Chunk` do, and what is `msg`?

Comment: Without being able to see your code, nobody will be able to answer this, but it's easy to write an enumerator that returns different values every time it's evaluated.

Comment: msg is a IEnumerabel<byte> that in every step of the loop LINQ's command is used on it.
Chunk is LINQ's command. You can [check the MS official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0)

Comment: The code is really large, and I cant post it here, since the project is private.

Comment: No matter how private the project or large the code, what you talk about is just a couple of lines similar to countless others. You can't even copyright or claim trade secrets on common practices, and that includes common code idioms. You should be able to create an example with just a few lines that demonstrates the problem

Comment: `a recursive LINQ command,` what does that mean for example? LINQ is a query language, it doesn't use recursion. It's not SQL, it has no CTEs. Post your code as *text* in the question itself, not as links to sites with adult warnings

Comment: As for why `IEnumerable<T>` values change - `IEnumerable` isn't a container, it's an interface for iterating stuff. With static data, the values you get depend on where you start in the data. If you have an iterator method, the values you get will be anything the method produces when it runs, so there's no guarantee what you'll get. When you query unordered data, there's no guarantee you'll get the same sequence of values every time

Comment: I know, and don't believe it is `a recursive LINQ command`, it is just the way I tired to explain the problem. But now Ondrej Tucny suggested a more realistic explanation. I think that this amount of code that I shared is enough to find the reason of the problem.

Comment: The explanation is `that's now what IEnumerable does`. You haven't posted any code yet. I don't know if that answer is even relevant. But yes, *iterating* over an enumerable to show its values ... iterates the values

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger has to actually enumerate the `newMsg`, which causes your code in `SelectMany` to execute. The `keyEnumerator` keeps being enumerated, never 'reset' between debugger's enumerations of `newMsg`. That may lead to different results each time.

That's also why the user interface tells you that *“Expanding the Results View will enumerate IEnumerable”*. Unless it is a static collection, which is *not* in your case, the results will differ each time.

Comment: I get what you are saying, and I agree with you. But isn't calling GetEnumerator() again equivalent to Resetting the Enumerator? Initially I wanted to use Reset(), but compiler gave me "System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'"

Comment: @Micra it's not and you shouldn't use `.Reset()`. There's no need to do that to walk through a bunch of values. Besides, if the data comes from another source, eg a database query, the contents *and* order depend on that source. Post your code in the question itself

Comment: I have tried to simulate the behavior in simpler code, where it worked without `.Reset()`
(I will add the code in main question)

Comment: @Micra The problem is _not_ the `IEnumerable newMsg` itself. The root cause of your issue lies in the delegate passed to `SelectMany`, which in turn calls `keyEnumerator.MoveNext()` a _this_ is never reset between enumerations of `newMsg`.

Comment: @Micra The 'simple example' code you added to your question is *not* equivalent to the inner workings of your original code. The original code has *dynamic behavior* due to dynamic _data_. The second example has *static behavior* thanks to static _data_.

Comment: You're Goddamn right :). Thanks for helping me, I have not noticed that I had an error in my written logic.